# jQuery scroll to element after element animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I'm having a bit of an animation scrolling issue and have exhausted my debugging efforts.  In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is scroll to an open panel on the users click.  User clicks on 1 of a series of panels, that panel opens up (animates), and the freshly opened panel scrolls into view.  Simple enough.

The problem I'm having is that if I click on a panel that is below an already open panel the scrolling pulls my new open panel half way off screen.  If I click a panel above an already open panel it works fine.  Not sure what is going on.  I'm animating the panel opening with CSS and using jQuery to animate the scrolling.  I'm assuming there is some animation queue timing that is causing the issue but I don't know.  I even tried to delay the scroll animation to wait for the panel to finish it's animation but that didn't help either.  For example:

```
$('html, body').delay(1000).animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 75}, 250);
```

Instead of

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 75}, 250);
```

Anyway, any help would be appreciated.  You can find the code I'm working with here: https://jsfiddle.net/66zzudo4/

> UPDATE: You can find the working code here: https://jsfiddle.net/66zzudo4/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using a timeout would work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 75}, 250);
}, 1000);
```

Or, jquery animate also takes a callback as an argument when the animation finishes:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 75}, function() {
 //Animation complete, do something now like animate other stuff.
}, 250);
```

Comment: the setTimeout worked.  The issue was definitely the panel closing animation.  The value of the panels height was still being represented as expanded when the original scroll line of code was executed.  Using a timeout solved the issue as the code was not executed until the timeout.  Interesting that the delay function does work the same way.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .top

```
  $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset() - 75
            }, 250);
```

Check it here. It works. https://jsfiddle.net/66zzudo4/1/

Comment: the link you sent has the code with .top still there.  I removed .top from the code and no scroll animation happens at all.  the goal is to scroll and open panel 75 pixels from the top.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I must have not saved it. It works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/66zzudo4/2/

Comment: No worries, thanks for help.  But the animation scroll doesn't happen at all.  The panel simply opens in place and never scrolls into view 75 pixels from the top.